# Why this is a martingale?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, random-variables, martingales, conditional-expectation

Setup:

$W$ probability space

$Z_i : W \to L_i $ random variables ($L_i$ finite, for example $\{0,1\}$)

$f: Z_1 \times \ldots \times Z_n \to \mathbb{R}$

$X_i := \mathbb{E}[f \mid Z_1,..,Z_i]$

Why is $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ a martingale?

For beeing a martingale it has to fulfill

$\mathbb{E}[X_{i+1} \mid X_1,..,X_i] = X_i$

so I have to show (because $X_i$ is determined by $Z_1,\ldots,Z_i$

$\mathbb{E}[X_{i+1} \mid X_1,\ldots,X_i] = \mathbb{E}[X_{i+1} \mid Z_1\ldots,Z_i] = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[f \mid Z_1,\ldots,Z_{i+1}] \mid Z_1\ldots,Z_i]= \ldots =\mathbb{E}[F\mid Z_1,\ldots,Z_i]=X_i$

I don't get the "intention" behind it…the conditional expectation of the conditional expectation of $f$ (knowing $Z_1,\ldots,Z_{i+1}$) knowing $Z_1,\ldots,Z_i$ is the conditional expectation of $f$ knowing $Z_1,\ldots,Z_i$ ???

Comment: What do you mean by $f:Z_1 \times \ldots \times Z_n \to \mathbb{R}$? A function, defined on a product of random variables? What's that supposed to mean? (I have improved the formatting, please check whether I didn't change the meaning of your question.)

Comment: Also are you sure you meant to define $ X_i$ as an expected value because then each $ X_i $ is just a number not a random variable

Comment: @user159813 It is a conditional expectation, therefore $X_i$ is not just a number.

Comment: Lol of course sometimes I comment without thinking sorry about that

Comment: oh sorry, f is defined on L_1 x .. x L_n . For example think about each Z_i maps into {0,1} and f gives you the sum f(w) = Z_1(w) + .. + Z_n(w)

Comment: thx for editing … let me explain the first equality: look at the constant levels of the random variables in W: A_(l_1,…,l_i) = \cap {Z_j=l_j} (the subset in W, where Z_j=l_j for j=1,…,i) and B_(k_1,…,k_i) = \cap {X_j=k_j} j=1,…,i . These families give your a partition of W (if you ignore empty subsets) and each A_(l_1,…,l_i) is contained in some B_(k_1,…,k_i). thats why conditioning on X_1,…,X_i is the same like conditioning on Z_1,…,Z_i . (Is there some tutorial how to use this formeleditor?)

Comment: @crank See http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex. So, $f$ is a function of $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$, i.e. $f=g(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ for some function $g$, right?

Comment: exactly, so its implicitly defined on W

Comment: I guess I'm done using the tower property of conditional experience: $E[X_{i+1}|X_1,…,X_i]=E[X_{i+1}|Z_1,…,Z_i]=E[E[f|Z_1,…,Z_{i+1}]|Z_1,…,Z_i]=E[f|Z_1,…,Z_i]$

Comment: @crank Yes, exactly, this follows directly form the tower property.